# Take k smallest numbers from a list time complixity in Haskell

Tags: algorithm, haskell, time-complexity

Is the time complexity of the next Haskell programm `n * log(n)` or `n * log(k)`*? If it's the latter, then how does Haskell achieve that?

```
import Data.List

takeKSmallest :: [Int] -> Int -> [Int]
takeKSmallest numbers k = take k $ sort numbers
```

* `n` is the length of the input list. `k` is the number of the first elements we want to return.

Comment: If you sorted a whole list of n elements, using quickshort, the complexity would be n * log(n).
But you don't need to sort the entire list if you just want to find the k smallest elements, so the cost has to be lower. In a sense, you only need to order the k-first elements from low to high, that's where you get the "k" in the log.